# How would you add a lot of images to an UIview?

Tags: iphone

I have to put a lot of images (>100) to a UIView, with touch detection. If I use UIImageViewController I have ran out of memory. I've tried to draw the images manually, but in that case I can't detect which image has been pushed.

So how would you do this?

Comment: Why would you put 100 images on the screen? What are you really trying to do? Do you need to browse these images? Please explain a bit more what your is supposed to do.

Comment: I'm displaying music artworks, and I've got 130 albums on my iPhone 3G, and I guess, there are a lot of people, who has more on it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, you might want to try creating thumbnail sized images to display that will take up much less memory (100 times 32 pixels x 32 pixels x 4 channels is definitely small enough for the iPhone to handle).  For a more robust solution, you want to look at doing lazy loading and only keep in memory those images that are currently being displayed.  There is a great example of this in a CoverFlow clone found in Ch 12 of iPhone SDK Application Development, which you can see [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154059/)

Comment: Yepp, that could be work, if I don't want to zoom the images. :( So the thumbnail is unfortunately not a great option, and the lazy loading is fail, since I have to display every image. (in a 0.4 zoomed scrollView for example).